# Debugging parallel Python programs (mpi4py)

Tags: python, debugging, parallel-processing, trace, mpi4py

I have an `mpi4py` program that hangs intermittently. How can I trace what the individual processes are doing?

I can run the program in different terminals, for example using `pdb`

```
mpiexec -n 4 xterm -e "python -m pdb my_program.py"
```

But this gets cumbersome if the issue only manifests with a large number of processes (~80 in my case). In addition, it's easy to catch exceptions with `pdb` but I'd need to see the trace to figure out where the hang occurs.

Answer (score 3):

The Python [trace](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/trace.html) module allows you to trace program execution. In order to store the trace of each process separately, you need to wrap your code in a function:

```
def my_program(*args, **kwargs):
    # insert your code here
    pass
```

And then run it with `trace.Trace.runfunc`:

```
import sys
import trace

# define Trace object: trace line numbers at runtime, exclude some modules
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    ignoremods=[
        'inspect', 'contextlib', '_bootstrap',
        '_weakrefset', 'abc', 'posixpath', 'genericpath', 'textwrap'
    ],
    trace=1,
    count=0)

# by default trace goes to stdout
# redirect to a different file for each processes
sys.stdout = open('trace_{:04d}.txt'.format(COMM_WORLD.rank), 'w')

tracer.runfunc(my_program)
```

Now the trace of each process will be written in a separate file `trace_0001.txt` etc. Use `ignoredirs` and `ignoremods` arguments to omit low level calls.